# Как сделать вывод ошибок видными только для меня на opencarte 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart

Как сделать вывод ошибок видными только для меня (одного или определенного пользователя) на opencart

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

Я хочу чтобы ошибки выводились только для одного пользователя (для меня), остальные их не видели.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Первое что нужно отметить, вам необходимо зарегистрироваться на сайте в качестве покупателя.

**Первый вариант**

Необходимо открыть файл `\system\framework.php`

Найти строки:

```
// Session
$session = new Session();

if ($config->get('session_autostart')) {
    $session->start();
}

$registry->set('session', $session);
```

И ниже добавить:

```
if( isset($_SESSION[$_COOKIE['default']]['customer_id']) AND $_SESSION[$_COOKIE['default']]['customer_id'] == 1 ) {  // где 1 это идентификатор покупателя
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
}
```

**Второй вариант**

Необходимо открыть файл `\catalog\controller\common\header.php`

Найти метод `public function index() {` и в самое его начало добавить:

```
if( $this->customer->isLogged() AND $this->customer->getId() == 1 ){
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
}
```

---

Но на самом деле я бы не рекомендовал так делать. Лучше перенести сайт на локалку и отладить весь код.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Использовал первый вариант. Почему не рекомендуете так делать ?

Comment: @СерегаОн Первый вариант подразумевает правку файлов движка. И если обновите движок, что правки слетят. Во втором варианте могу быть пропущены некоторые ошибки. А так если всё работает, обновлять движок не собираетесь, то можете оставить так.

Comment: Alexander Semikashev, а какие еще варианты могут быть ? На сайте стоит обратный прокси и по ip не особо получается.А ошибки возникают при регистрации, поэтому личный кабинет не очень подходит.Спасибо

Comment: @СерегаОн насколько мне известно, вариантов больше нет.